# Calculation using interpolating function

Tags: interpolation

Say I have two replacement rules in terms of interpolating functions.

```
Rule1 = {z -> Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2 + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]]};

Rule2 = {x -> Interpolation[Table[{i, Sin[i] + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]]};
```

Now consider I have a function which I cannot evaluate by any other means except only by replacing the above rules.

```
func = Sin[x z]/(x + z)^2 /. Flatten[{Rule1, Rule2}]
```

What is the way to get the function value at any `i`?

Note: Actually, in a multibody dynamics code I have obtained 6 variables as replacement rules of interpolating functions. Now I need to compute another quantity which is a very large function of these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using replacement rules (yet), let's see a model of what *will* work:

```
Rule1z = Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2 + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]];
Rule2x = Interpolation[Table[{i, Sin[i] + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]];
fun[i_] = Sin[Rule2x[i] Rule1z[i]]/(Rule2x[i] + Rule1z[i])^2;
fun[1.2]

(* -0.0267361 *)
```

Following that model, we can use the replacement rules this way:

```
Rule1 = {z -> Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2 + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]]};
Rule2 = {x -> Interpolation[Table[{i, Sin[i] + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]]};
RuleAz = z /. Rule1;
RuleBx = x /. Rule2;
fun2[i_] = Sin[RuleBx[i] RuleAz[i]]/(RuleBx[i] + RuleAz[i])^2;
fun2[1.2]

(* -0.0267361 *)
```

This suggests a more compact version that also works.

```
fun3[i_] = Sin[x[i] z[i]]/(x[i] + z[i])^2 /. Flatten[{Rule1, Rule2}];
fun3[1.2]

(* -0.0267361 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to supply an argument to the `InterpolatingFunction` in each rule.  This way the replacement replaces a variable representing a number with an expression representing the value of an `InterpolatingFunction`. It replace something with a thing of the same kind (a number).

```
Rule1[k_] = {z -> Interpolation[Table[{i, i^2 + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]][k]};
Rule2[k_] = {x -> Interpolation[Table[{i, Sin[i] + i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]][k]};
```

Using `func` as an expression depending on `i`, with two evaluation options:

```
func = Sin[x z]/(x + z)^2 /. Flatten[{Rule1[i], Rule2[i]}];

func /. i -> 1
(*  -0.0349188  *)

Block[{i = 1}, func]
(*  -0.0349188  *)
```

Defining `func` as a function:

```
ClearAll[func];
func[i_] = Sin[x z]/(x + z)^2 /. Flatten[{Rule1[i], Rule2[i]}];

func[1]
func[1.2]
(*  -0.0349188  *)
(*  -0.0267361  *)
```